# Extract and convert from JSON by Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Good afternoon, it is necessary to extract the data inside the token_dict object from the data received by the api and convert the data, example:

```
"token_dict": {
  "0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06": {
    "chain": "bsc",
    "decimals": 18,
    "display_symbol": null,
    "id": "0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06",
    "is_core": true,
    "is_verified": true,
    "is_wallet": true,
    "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/bsc_token/logo_url/0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06/8dfc8adee7cc793678ec6d572b4d7e43.png",
    "name": "SpaceY Token",
    "optimized_symbol": "SPAY",
    "price": 1.0733528304908733,
    "protocol_id": "",
    "symbol": "SPAY",
    "time_at": 1621572439
  },
  "0xd9ec19fe88140ac0a3ab5517f8e54a2143599f80": {
    "chain": "bsc",
    "decimals": 18,
    "display_symbol": null,
    "id": "0xd9ec19fe88140ac0a3ab5517f8e54a2143599f80",
    "is_core": null,
    "is_verified": null,
    "is_wallet": false,
    "logo_url": null,
    "name": "Phenomenal Protocol PNM Token",
    "optimized_symbol": "PNM",
    "price": 0,
    "protocol_id": "",
    "symbol": "PNM",
    "time_at": 1651860868
  }
}
```

Convert to this form:

```
"token_dict": [
  {
    "chain": "bsc",
    "decimals": 18,
    "display_symbol": null,
    "id": "0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06",
    "is_core": true,
    "is_verified": true,
    "is_wallet": true,
    "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/bsc_token/logo_url/0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06/8dfc8adee7cc793678ec6d572b4d7e43.png",
    "name": "SpaceY Token",
    "optimized_symbol": "SPAY",
    "price": 1.0733528304908733,
    "protocol_id": "",
    "symbol": "SPAY",
    "time_at": 1621572439
  },
 {
    "chain": "bsc",
    "decimals": 18,
    "display_symbol": null,
    "id": "0xd9ec19fe88140ac0a3ab5517f8e54a2143599f80",
    "is_core": null,
    "is_verified": null,
    "is_wallet": false,
    "logo_url": null,
    "name": "Phenomenal Protocol PNM Token",
    "optimized_symbol": "PNM",
    "price": 0,
    "protocol_id": "",
    "symbol": "PNM",
    "time_at": 1651860868
  }
]
```

That is, the data that needs to be received as a list at the output, and since I work on the Bubble platform, there are some difficulties with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that Regex is very far from the best solution to this issue.

A better approach to achieve what you require is to use `Object.keys()` to retrieve a list of all the unique property names within `token_dict` and then use `map()` to create an array of their associated object values:

```
Object.keys(data.token_dict).map(k => data.token_dict[k]);
```

Here's a working example of this:

```js
var data = {token_dict:{"0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06":{chain:"bsc",decimals:18,display_symbol:null,id:"0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06",is_core:!0,is_verified:!0,is_wallet:!0,logo_url:"https://static.debank.com/image/bsc_token/logo_url/0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06/8dfc8adee7cc793678ec6d572b4d7e43.png",name:"SpaceY Token",optimized_symbol:"SPAY",price:1.0733528304908733,protocol_id:"",symbol:"SPAY",time_at:1621572439},"0xd9ec19fe88140ac0a3ab5517f8e54a2143599f80":{chain:"bsc",decimals:18,display_symbol:null,id:"0xd9ec19fe88140ac0a3ab5517f8e54a2143599f80",is_core:null,is_verified:null,is_wallet:!1,logo_url:null,name:"Phenomenal Protocol PNM Token",optimized_symbol:"PNM",price:0,protocol_id:"",symbol:"PNM",time_at:1651860868}}};

var output = Object.keys(data.token_dict).map(k => data.token_dict[k]);
console.log(output);
```

Note that this is assuming that you do not have the ability to correct the response data format from your API on the server side. That would *by far* be the best approach to solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wanted to use regex to remove all unnecessary, but your solution is much better. Could you tell me what it will look like when I have such a json structure:
https://i2.paste.pics/de92405b581d158a98b3de3e2ca7c743.png?trs=c584a5647e502bd9961f792b11d8b023a75e174f7cddb0d60ce555e0ac01ae25

Comment: In that case change `data.token_dict` to `data.bsc.token_dict` - where `data` is a reference to the top level object.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but is it possible to get data from all the lists? That is, from arb, astar, bsc, etc?

Answer (score 0):

a simple map function would sufice

```
   const data = { "token_dict": {
      "0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06": {
        "chain": "bsc",
        "decimals": 18,
        "display_symbol": null,
        "id": "0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06",
        "is_core": true,
        "is_verified": true,
        "is_wallet": true,
        "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/bsc_token/logo_url/0x13a637026df26f846d55acc52775377717345c06/8dfc8adee7cc793678ec6d572b4d7e43.png",
        "name": "SpaceY Token",
        "optimized_symbol": "SPAY",
        "price": 1.0733528304908733,
        "protocol_id": "",
        "symbol": "SPAY",
        "time_at": 1621572439
      },
      "0xd9ec19fe88140ac0a3ab5517f8e54a2143599f80": {
        "chain": "bsc",
        "decimals": 18,
        "display_symbol": null,
        "id": "0xd9ec19fe88140ac0a3ab5517f8e54a2143599f80",
        "is_core": null,
        "is_verified": null,
        "is_wallet": false,
        "logo_url": null,
        "name": "Phenomenal Protocol PNM Token",
        "optimized_symbol": "PNM",
        "price": 0,
        "protocol_id": "",
        "symbol": "PNM",
        "time_at": 1651860868
      }
    }
   }
   const formated_data = {
 "token_dict" : Object.values(a.token_dict).map(token=> token})
}
```